# string format for long parameters

Tags: c#

I am building a string using the string.Format method. Often, I will have very long parameter lists for tables with many columns for example

```
string query = string.Format("{0},{1},{2},...,{30}", val1, val2, ...., val30);
```

Does C# have a more concise way of dealing with such strings?

Comment: You are building sql queries with `string.Format`?? Have you ever heard of sql-injection?

Comment: Use Parameterized Queries, instead of using `String.Format`

Comment: Not sure if there is a better way but just off the topic why dont you use a stored procedure that can take parameters rather than using string as query. Have you heard of SQL Injection?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Indeed I have. This isn't a web facing application, and there probably will only be one user of the application. I'm reading from text files, doing some processing then insert into the database. The values do get "cleaned up" before database access. Thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: @YawarMurtaza SQL injection had been mentioned previously. Thanks.

Comment: Presumably your query will be run more than once with a different set of parameters, correct? If so, it's still beneficial to do the parameterized query due to giving the query planner an easier time.

Comment: @iab: there is never ever an excuse for using string concatenation instead of  parameterized queries. Maybe you will never have any problems(sql-injection, localization issues, performance problems or wrong conversions). But maybe this will explode some time. Why you want to risk it?

Comment: Why is people down voting the question? While it is definitely not a good practice, that is exactly the kind of basic questions that I would like beginners to see, then find in the answers all the reasons not to follow the bad practice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string interpolation:

```
$"{val1},{val2},{val3}"
```

But I have to warn you: **do not build the SQL statement using `string.Format` and alike. [Use parameterized queries!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7505808/993547)**

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't aware of string interpolation :)

Answer (score 0):

**Do not build your queries with string.format or string interpolation**

There are built in methods to safely parameterize your queries:

```
string sql = "SELECT name from student where id = @id";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(someConnectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("id", someIdVariable));
    var results = command.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> I am building SQL queries using the string.Format method.

Well, that's your first mistake.  You're probably best of with one paramterized query.

But, ignoring that, your question was about building string.  And the best way to do that is with the `StringBuilder` object:

```
var sql = new StringBuilder();
sql.AppendFormat("{0},{1},{2},", val1, val2, val3);
sql.AppendFormat("{0},{1},{2},", val4, val5, val6);
```